# Qt5 QImageReader Strange Behavior

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, qt5, 32bit-64bit

I test a simple code using QImageReader

```
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    QPixmap pixmap;
    QImageReader reader("hubble.tif");
    reader.setClipRect(QRect(0,0,8000,8000));
    QImage img = reader.read();
    if (img.isNull())
        qDebug() << reader.errorString();
    else
    {
        pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
        scene->addPixmap(pixmap);
    }
```

When I compiled it with Qt5.3.2_MSVC 2013_OpenGl 64bit and I tested it with an image 18000x18000 (thanks [Nasa Hubble Image](http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2006-01-a-full_tif.tif)...), the program work without error.
When I test the same program but compiled with Qt5.3.2_MSVC 2013_OpenGl 32bit, the program fail with reader's error "Unable to read image data" !

Is this a bug in Qt or just a limitation of 32bit version that not mentionned in Qt Documentation ?

Comment: I've had trouble with large .tif files on Qt5.4.0_MSVC 2010_OpenGL 32bit also. Not sure what causes it though...

Comment: I convert this image to png format but I have the same behavior !
I think is in related with memory allocation problem but no informations is mentionned in Qt documentaion. An other thing is that QImageReader, normally, don't load image in memory but I think it do that when reading !

Answer (score 0):

An image that size needs 18000 * 18000 * 23 = 1.266GB of contiguous memory, which on a 32 bit system your program might not have.  You might find this helpful in how to split it up into smaller chunks.  https://forum.qt.io/topic/4270/qimagereader-setcliprect-limitation-on-size-large-image/4

Comment: First, I think in Win32 system dynamic virtual memory up to 2GB / process.
Then QImageReader load Image and after that it conserv only the desired part. Loading image is not possible so QImageReader fail !

Comment: Are you sure libpng allows to load only a subset of the image? If you're *positive* about this, feel free to open a bug report against QImageReader. If libpng decodes the entire image then there's nothing Qt can do...